# Change state of checkbox by Listbox items selection c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, listbox

I have a `listbox`named (**lstClass**) filled with database items. I want to change the state of `checkbox` named (**cbSelectAll**) placed outside the `listbox`. I want these points to implement in code,

1. When form loads, the Checkbox should be set to `false`.
2. When I select multiple items(Not complete items) from Listbox, Checkbox state should be changed to `Intermediate`.
3. When I select complete items form Listbox, Checkbox state should be changed to `True`.
4. When I Click checkbox, if its state is `true` then **all** items should be selected in ListBox.
5. When I click checkbox, if its state is `false` then **no** items should be selected in Listbox.

The code for the form is under:-

```
public partial class frmSelectClass : Form
{
    private DataTable dTable;
    
    public frmSelectClass(DataTable table)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dTable = table;
    }

    private void frmSelectClass_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Retrieving_SheetNames();
    }

    private void Retrieving_SheetNames()
    {
        List<string> lstSheets;
        // Get sheet names from excel
        List<string> lstSheetsEx = dTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME").Trim(new char[] { '\'', '$' })).ToList();
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from Classes", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dtClassDb = new DataTable();
                dtClassDb.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                // Get sheet names from Access DB
                List<string> lstSheetsdb = dtClassDb.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("Class")).ToList();
                // Order sheet names according to DB
                lstSheets = lstSheetsdb.Intersect(lstSheetsEx).Union(lstSheetsEx).ToList();
            }
        }
        lstClass.DataSource = lstSheets;
    }
   
    private void cbSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbSelectAll.Checked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstClass.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                lstClass.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lstClass.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            lstClass.SetSelected(i, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `SelectedValueChanged` event for the `ListBox` something like this:

```
private void lstClass_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbSelectAll.CheckedChanged -= cbSelectAll_CheckedChanged;
    if (lstClass.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        cbSelectAll.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    else if (lstClass.SelectedItems.Count == lstClass.Items.Count)
        cbSelectAll.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
    else
        cbSelectAll.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
    cbSelectAll.CheckedChanged += cbSelectAll_CheckedChanged;

}
```

Comment: This is working for me. When checkbox is checked, and it clicked its state changed to Indeterminate but nothing happens in listbox selected items. Still all items selected.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the items?

Comment: Indeterminate state means not all items selected, This is what i want

Comment: If you set `ThreeState` to `false`, you won't be able to put `cbSelectAll` into the indeterminate state by clicking in it. I removed the last sentence from my answer :)

Comment: ok now worked. I want no items should be selected when the forms loads.

Comment: Call `lstClass.SelectedItems.Clear()` in `frmSelectClass_Load`.

Comment: When the form loads, the `SelectedValueChanged` method called automatically. is there a way to stop it on form loads?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. If you post the link to it here, I'll try to help you out.